# forcefully / manually remove content type

Tags: 7, nodes, features

Is it possible to manually remove a content type?

I've packaged it in a feature and now the content type is no longer needed; it's been deprecated. I'm unable to delete the content type after disabling the feature in the features panel and in the modules page.

Answer (score 1):

If you have devel install then go to sitename/devel/php and execute the following code.

```
node_type_delete('content_type_machine_name');
```

else you can run the same code inside hook_init() of your custom module.
Hope it helps.